# how to find stability index by calculating the average variance between each frames per second?

Tags: python, statistics

I have my data for FPS in table, like:

T: FPS

1: 30

2: 15

3: 25

4: 26

5:20

etc

I want to find the FPS **stability index**. sum of all values for FPS and divide by number? it is just average, but not sure that it will show the data i am looking for. I am not good in statistics and looking for any help. I want to write it in Python, but language does not matter, more important is the logic of calculation. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming a definition of "stability index" taken from the following question: [Population stability index](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79561/population-stability-index-division-by-zero)

That requires having 2 series in the first place: a base and a target one. If you don't have them, I fail to find a definition of "stability index" that can make your case. Instead, you may be interested in the [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) of the FPS serie.

To calculate the stdev of a list `fps` of numbers, you can use the following code:

```
from math import sqrt
fps = [30, 15, 25, 26, 20]
fps_stdev = sqrt(sum(x**2 for x in fps)/len(fps)-(sum(fps)/len(fps))**2)
# fps_stdev == 5.192301994298871
```

which computes the average squares, subtracts the square of the average, and finally extracts the square root.

---

edit: the following code should compute the population stability index as [defined](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79561/population-stability-index-division-by-zero). You can change `bins` and `target` to different lengths and values.  I propose as target a uniform distribution between 25 and 35.

```
import math
fps = [30, 15, 25, 26, 20, 15, 20, 30, 26, 25]
bins = [0, 25, 30, 35, 1000]
target = [0.001,0.499,0.499,0.001]
base   = [sum(1 for x in fps if low<=x<high)/len(fps)
          for low, high in zip(bins[:-1],bins[1:])]
psi = sum((a-b)*math.log((a+1e-9)/b) for a, b in zip(base, target))
# psi == 2.7065829626120728
```

Or in a function using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
bins = [0, 25, 30, 35, 1000]
target = np.array([0.001,0.499,0.499,0.001])

def psi(fps):
    base = np.histogram(fps, bins=bins)[0]/len(fps)
    return np.sum((base-target)*np.log(1e-9 + base/target))
```

Which gives the following results:

```
psi([30, 15, 25, 26, 20, 15, 20, 30, 26, 25])  # 2.7065829626120728
psi(np.random.uniform(20,40,[1000000]))  # 3.0929707119205654
psi(np.random.uniform(24,36,[1000000]))  # 0.75734794293362917
psi(np.random.uniform(25,35,[1000000]))  # 0.041450536356554171
psi(np.random.uniform(26,34,[1000000]))  # 0.041450567333546476
psi(np.random.uniform(29,31,[1000000]))  # 0.041450706905843779
psi(np.random.uniform(29,37,[1000000]))  # 1.9470356968069937
psi(np.random.uniform(29,60,[1000000]))  # 7.0800113672962866
psi(np.random.uniform(35,60,[1000000]))  # 27.603390094813619
psi(np.random.uniform(0, 25,[1000000]))  # 27.603390094813619
```

Note that `np.log(1e-9 + base/target)`: if a base bin is empty, that `1e-9` avoids the log to go to -inf, but the last lines of the results above are very sensitive to the arbitrary choice of `1e-9`. Keep it in mind. Also, target bins must be > 0 to avoid division by zero.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I think the first case is closer what i am looking for, cause my target value is 30 always.

Comment: For that metric you have to assume a target *distribution*. Instead, if you have a single value as a target, it makes more sense to consider the RMSE or MAPE. Anyway I'm going to edit the answer to include an example code that may be useful.